# On a ratio of probabilities

Tags: probability

At work, we keep using the following coefficient:

$$\frac{P(B|A)}{P(B)} \equiv \frac{P(A, B)}{P(A) P(B)}$$

In order to understand correlation among some events (we estimate this from samples). I realize that this is not a proper probability, but it has helped in practice.

The question we keep asking ourselves is, does this have a name?

Comment: What is $P(A, B)$? The probability of the intersection?

Comment: Notice you can cancel $P(B)$ from both sides, then this is just a definition of conditional probability.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork and B.Mehta: you seem to misunderstand the question. It is asking whether the quantity introduced is standard enough and has a name, not how to derive the equality...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be known as *observed to expected ratio* in medical sciences. See e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/79216/75808) (or [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6047/does-this-quantity-related-to-independence-have-a-name), which references it as well).